# LINQ Query Syntax (Count Operation)

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have a LINQ statement which works fine with Method Syntax. Am curious to see how would the equivalent query syntax look like. Tried doing multiple iterations but couldn't succeed with query syntax

Currently I have 2 strings - one being a sentence and other being an alphabet. I convert both of them into character for comparison - so I can find the number of occurrences of the character in the full string.

```
string sentenceToScan = "I Love StackOverflow!!!!";
string characterToScanFor = "e";

var stringToCheckAsCharacterArray = sentenceToScan.ToCharArray();
var characterToCheckFor = Char.Parse(characterToScanFor);

int numberOfOccurenes = stringToCheckAsCharacterArray.Count(n =>
                                              n == characterToCheckFor);

Answer: 2
```

Comment: I think answer is 2. `I Lov(e) StackOv(e)rflow!!!!`

Comment: :):) oops obvious typo :):)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Count` doesn't have a query expression syntax, it can only be appended at the end of a  query expression like:

```
var count = (from t in stringToCheckAsCharacterArray
            where t == characterToCheckFor).Count();
```

Or

```
var count = (from t in stringToCheckAsCharacterArray
            where t == characterToCheckFor
            select t).Count();
```

Personally I like Method expression, also [LINQ query expression compiles in Method expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx). Your own code for `Count` with predicate is more readable IMO.

Comment: Thanks - didnt know we could use the count function in such a way. Really appreciate and will mark this as an answer

Comment: @Habib- count can be used with a predicate such as Patrick suggested

Comment: @JeskoR., yes it can be, but it doesn't have a query syntax, like `Where` has `where` in query syntax, `Count` doesn't.

Comment: @Habib the predicate is of type Func(char,bool) so you can use lambda expressions as well and it works therefore as a condition like the where clause.

Comment: @JeskoR., you are right. But with Expression syntax, count doesn't have an equivalent :)

Comment: Does the first example work? It says "a query body must end with a select clause...".

Answer (score 0):

My LINQ is rusty, but something like:

```
stringToCheckAsCharacterArray.Where(n => n == characterToCheckFor).Count();
```

Comment: That's just different way to write equivalent query, but it's not the query syntax (`from … where … select`).